Self-hosted Gitlab Runner Configuration
I'm  learning how to set up self hosted runners in Gitlab with this video tutorial and have naive a question about the conceptional reason for configuring the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the way presented in the video.
In suggested configuation of the runner the execution program is choosen to be 'shell' and the shell parameter is choosen to be 'powershell' (see 5:25 in the video), so the relevant excerpt of the runner config file looks something like
[[runners]]
  name = "TestRunner"
  url = Blabla.com
  token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
 

Next - the part I actually not fully undestand - the setting up of a CI job the relevant excerpt of presented .gitlab-ci.yml file Inwould like to understand (see 7:00):

job_build:
    stage: built 
    tags: 
     - windows
    
    script:  
      - echo "Blabla"
      - cmd /c echo %PATH%
      - cmd /c echo %HOME%
      - cmd /c curl --version
      - cmd /c dir

   [...]


Question: What is the role of cmd command or/and why it is neccessary to use here?
I tried to make a script without - ie above replaced in the script part the cmd commands by
script:  
      - echo "Blabla"
      - /c echo %PATH%
      - /c echo %HOME%
      - /c curl --version
      - /c dir


but got an error.
Therefore my question is why it actually important to precompose all these shell commands by the cmd command? I thought that when above the shell parameter is set to 'powershell' it is clear that it's the powershell which executes all these commands, right? Why do we need to precompose cmd "additionally"?
So wouldn't precomposing cmd there be technically redundant as technically that all seems to be already manageble by the powershell shell?
Therefore I not understand the role & neccessarity for precomposing cmd command there.
Here seems tacitly hierarchy relation: powershell can call cmd.exe but not converse.
Of course, there might be pure historical reasons. But I would like to understand if there are also conceptional & technical reasons justifying this. Could somebody explain the involved mechanism behind justifying the role for precomposing cmd there?
